# how to fix OutOfMemoryError in ML Kit face detection?

Tags: android, out-of-memory, face-detection, google-mlkit

ML Kit Face Detector Options:

```
private val realTimeOpts = FaceDetectorOptions.Builder()
    .setPerformanceMode(FaceDetectorOptions.PERFORMANCE_MODE_ACCURATE)
    .setLandmarkMode(FaceDetectorOptions.LANDMARK_MODE_ALL)
    .setClassificationMode(FaceDetectorOptions.CLASSIFICATION_MODE_ALL)
    .setMinFaceSize(0.3f)
    .enableTracking()
    .build()

private val detector = FaceDetection.getClient(realTimeOpts)

fun detectInImage(image: InputImage): Task<List<Face>> {
    return detector.process(image)
}

fun stop() {
    try {
        detector.close()
    } catch (e: IOException) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Exception thrown while trying to close Face Detector: $e")
    }
}

@OptIn(ExperimentalCoroutinesApi::class)
suspend fun analyze(imageBitmap: Bitmap): Face? {

    return suspendCancellableCoroutine {

        val image: InputImage = InputImage.fromBitmap(imageBitmap, 0)

        detectInImage(image)
            .addOnSuccessListener { results ->
                it.resume(if (results.isNullOrEmpty()) null else results.firstOrNull()) {
                    it.printStackTrace()
                }
            }
            .addOnFailureListener {

            }
    }
}
```

When I try to detect faces from over 2000 bitmaps with this `analyze` method, the `OutOfMemoryError` exception occurs. I don't think my options are incorrect. How to release resources of detector? The `detector.close()` do nothing, I think. How to solve this issue?

Comment: Hi, I checked memory usage of mlkit sample app(https://github.com/googlesamples/mlkit/tree/master/android/vision-quickstart) using Android Studio profiler, and the memory usage seems stable. Based on current investigation I don't think there is memory leak inside mlkit. To further help you. Please 1) list out your device name, API level and RAM  2) follows the usage code in mlkit sample app and try it again  3) If you device is low end. Consider to resize the image to smaller one and then feed to ML Kit, also call bitmap.close() explicitly

Comment: @jack You are right. ML Kit is absolutely perfect. I found the memory leak outside of ML Kit. Thanks for commenting.